# Specify decimal places for float type in SailsJs

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I am using SailsJS with MySQL. How can I specify that a model field will have float type data with 10(let's say) decimal places?

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. Floating-point values don't have decimal places. They have binary places. Possibly you are looking for the `DECIMAL` type.